# cscript.exe crashes after script is executed on vista 64

Tags: com, vbscript, crash, windows-vista, wsh

I use a .vbs script that works fine on windows xp. Migrating to vista 64 or windows server 2008, my script does what it has to, but after the script is done, cscript.exe crashes.

I use the 32 bit version of cscript located in syswow64 as my script uses 32 bits old com object. Of course, I can't recompile these com objects.

adplus tells me that an access violation c0000005 is done on vista 64, not on xp.

After some search, I tried a registry hack in order to use 32 bit COM object which has failed, I tried to disable DEP which has failed.

Any ideas ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Seeing a crash you can use debugger to get minidump and call stacks and/or identify if there is a specific faulty module which crashes the process. Having isolated the problem like this you will find the reason of such odd behavior - it is not necessarily a script host which is causing the issue in first place.

Comment: Thanks, for the answer. yes seems that the problem comes from ntdll.dll according to the minidump.

Comment: @CastorMalin, this means that an invalid parameter was passed to the Win32 function. You need to look down the stack to find the first non-windows DLL. That's usually the one to blame.

Comment: I finally found a registry hack (dll surrogate) that allowed me to use 64 bit cscript. That works fine now.